# Can a value be Added Under the Registry Key DoNotDisableAddinList

Tags: registry, installation, outlook-addin, windows-installer

Can an msi be used to add a value to **HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DoNotDisableAddinList**?

Currently I'm getting an error

> Could not write *Addin_Name* to Key **\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DoNotDisableAddinList**.  Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel.

I'm an Administrator on the machine from which the MSI is being run.

Comment: You don't need to be administrator to access HKCU branch, user permissions are enough. What you need to make sure is the path you trying to set key/value pair is exists, otherwise create it before setting the pair. why do you set something into this key at the first place? You shouldn't do that. this key is for end users, definitely not for setting via MSI. Looks like hack, isn't it?

Comment: It's absolutely a hack :)

In the past we've had some trouble with Add-Ins being "slow" on startup, so now management would like to simply make the addition during installation and avoid "slow load" problems.

NOTE:  In my Installer code I've made sure that the path did exist with a conditional statement.

Comment: @Germán Have a look at your [registry table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371168%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) of the MSI with [Orca](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557(v=vs.85).aspx). You should have Root of your key set to 1 (HKCU) and Key should be starting with "Software..." (without slash, as mention @MichaelUrman). If you are creating this key dynamically with some CA, show your code. make sure Outlook 2013 installed as you specified version "15.0" in your path.

Comment: @Germán If at the end you will decide to make it right this post will help: [Support for Keeping Add-ins Enabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/support-for-keeping-add-ins-enabled?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @MichaelUrman,

I am using InstallAware 18.   The root is set to HKEY_CURRENT_USER and the Path I provided is set to "Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DoNotDisableAddinList"

The more I think about this, the more I don't like the solution even if I could do it through an msi.  It would seem to me that if the Add-In should experience a crash on loading that you would want Outlook NOT to load the thing.

However, that's a conversation to have with management.

I will double check my code and post my findings.  

thank you for your input.

Comment: Sounds like you need to check the permissions on that key (after it's written), and/or watch the error scenario with Process Monitor. Perhaps it's looking at a different key, or in a different way than you expect. Permissions should not be a problem in HKCU, but clearly something is off here.

Comment: Thanks for the link @SlavaIvanov.   I'll be adding it to our Knowledge base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we eventually ended up doing was

1) Exporting the registry value to a .reg file

**Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DoNotDisableAddinList]
"Your.AddinName"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DoNotDisableAddinList]
"Your.AdinName"=dword:00000001**

2) Created Batch File

**@echo off**

**reg ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DoNotDisableAddinList" /v "Your.AddinName" /t REG_DWORD /d 1
reg ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DoNotDisableAddinList" /v "Your.AddinName" /t REG_DWORD /d 1**

3) From Installer call Regedit.exe ("/s" option) on the .reg file created in step 1.

4) From Installer call batch file created in step 2.